# Seconds of Magnus Carlsen

Tags: world-championship, carlsen, preparation

Has it been revealed who helped Magnus Carlsen in preparing and during the World Chess Championship against Karjakin?

Comment: The RadioJan character on twitter claims to have been a second https://twitter.com/RadioJan/status/806133661934428160

Comment: More seriously, here are some of them: https://www.nrk.no/sport/dette-er-carlsens-hemmelige-hjelpere-1.13253569

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So far, following seconds have been revealed ([NRK](https://www.nrk.no/sport/dette-er-carlsens-hemmelige-hjelpere-1.13253569), [ChessBase](http://en.chessbase.com/post/carlsen-karjakin-interview-with-peter-heine-nielsen)):

- GM Peter Heine Nielsen (no surprise as he was part of team Carlsen in [WCC 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_2014))
- GM Laurent Fressinet (also no surprise as he was part of team Carlsen in [WCC 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_2013) and [WCC 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_2014))
- GM Maxime Vachier-Lagrave (quite a surprise as he is the [current world's nr. 4](http://www.2700chess.com/))
- GM Nils Grandelius
- GM Jan Gustafsson (the [tweet of RadioJan](https://twitter.com/RadioJan/status/806133661934428160) was not a joke)
- GM Samuel Shankland (a surprise to many, however it was revealed that [he also helped for WCC 2014](https://twitter.com/PHChess/status/806457832275083264))

Another surprise is that GM Jon Ludvig Hammer was *not* part of Carlsen's team for this match, while he was for [WCC 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_2013) and [WCC 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_2014). Instead, he chose to do commentary work for [VG and Chess.com](https://www.chess.com/nl/news/how-to-follow-carlsen-vs-karjakin-on-chess-com-1761).

Comment: GM Jan Gustafsson also (source: http://en.chessbase.com/post/carlsen-karjakin-interview-with-peter-heine-nielsen ). That RadioJan tweet was real. Yes he was also commentating for Chess24.

Comment: Correct! Actually, I thought that the tweet might be a joke, so originally I didn't put Gustaffson in the list. I edited the post.